# Authenticate Azure Email Communication Services using Service Principals in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-communication-services

I am attempting to create an API in my Azure Static Web App which sends an email when a form submission occurs in my app.

I was able to get this working by passing a connection string to the EmailClient, but I would prefer to authenticate my [EmailClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-communication-email/azure.communication.email.emailclient?view=azure-python-preview) using Azure's Service Principals as recommended in [the email quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/send-email?pivots=programming-language-python) and briefly explained in [the SMS quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/send?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-python).

I have tried passing an DefaultAzureCredential() as in the SMS quickstart

```
email_client = EmailClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=DefaultAzureCredential())
```

But I get an error saying `expected bytes or ASCII` in the credential parameter.

I then attempted to generate a token from the credential using the Client ID of the Email Communication Services object, so I could pass this as the credential per [the identity docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scopes-oidc#the-default-scope), but I get an error saying that the scope has not been provided:

```
credential=DefaultAzureCredential()
token=credential.get_token(scopes="bbjkl-xyz-abc/.default").token
email_client = EmailClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=token)

DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. 
Attempted credentials:
    EnvironmentCredential: "get_token" requires at least one scope
```

How do I authenticate the EmailClient using service principals? Or is this - as I suspect - a bug?

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

*Initially, I tried the EmailClient with Defaultcredentials and got same error:*

[image]

TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'DefaultAzureCredential'

As a workaround for authentication to send an email using **`EmailClient`** I tried to use **`Azurekeycredential`** method to send an email to the recipient.

**Code:**

```
from azure.communication.email import EmailClient,EmailAddress,EmailContent,EmailRecipients,EmailMessage
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

end="< your communication endpoint >"
cred=AzureKeyCredential(key="< key of azure communication service >")
email=EmailClient(endpoint=end,credential=cred)
content = EmailContent(
    subject="Welcome to Azure Communication Services Email",
    plain_text="This email message is sent from Azure Communication Services Email using the Python SDK.",
)

address = EmailAddress(email="demomail.com")
recipient = EmailRecipients(to=[address])

message = EmailMessage(
            sender="DoNotReply@xxxxxxxxxx.azurecomm.net",
            content=content,
            recipients=recipient
        )

response = email.send(message)
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Mail:**
The above code executed successfully by send mail to recipient with **`Azurekeycredential`** method.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure.communication.email.EmailClient class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-communication-email/azure.communication.email.emailclient?view=azure-python-preview)

Comment: Thanks for this. What would the advantage of using a KeyCredential over a connection string be?

Comment: @Solo The connection string is essentially the endpoint + "KeyCredential" (access key), there's not really a difference

Answer (score 0):

This is still in preview, so it's not well documented. I can't answer how to use the provided library, but here's an example using the REST API with service principal authentication.

Note your principal needs the **Contributor** role on the **Azure Communication Service** as well

```
import msal
import requests
import uuid
from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

def get_token_with_client_secret(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id):
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id         = client_id,
        client_credential = client_secret,
        authority         = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}")

    scopes = ["https://communication.azure.com/.default"]

    token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes = scopes)

    return(token)

def main():
    tenant_id = ""
    client_id = ""
    client_secret = ""
    endpoint = "https://endpoint.communication.azure.com/"
    sender = "DoNotReply@guid.azurecomm.net"
    
    # Obtain a token using the application credentials
    cred = get_token_with_client_secret(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id)
    
    # Generate timestamp to use in the repeatability-first-sent header    
    now = datetime.now()
    stamp = mktime(now.timetuple())
    time = format_date_time(stamp)

    request_url = f"{endpoint}emails:send?api-version=2021-10-01-preview"

    request_headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + cred["access_token"],
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "repeatability-request-id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
        "repeatability-first-sent": time
    }

    request_body = {
        "Sender": sender,
        "Content": {
            "Subject": "Email Subject",
            "PlainText": "This is the email body"
        },
        "Importance": "Normal",
        "Recipients": {
            "To": [
                {
                    "Email": "user@company.com",
                    "DisplayName": "User"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    response = requests.post(url = request_url, headers = request_headers, json = request_body)

main()
```